# why i m null getting value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

here is my controller i don't know why i have null value i check using dd($user)

```
  public function success1(Request $request)
   { 

   $phonetoken = $request->input('phonetoken');

      $user =User::where('phonetoken', $phonetoken)->first();


       dd($user);
        if(!is_null($user)){
        $user->phoneconfirmed = 1;
        $user->phonetoken = " ";
        $user->save();

       return redirect('sellerdashboard');
       }

       return redirect()->back();
     }
```

why i m not getting value in $user always getting null

Comment: You're getting `null` because there is no user with `phonetoken = $phonetoken`. Check the `users` table and `phonetoken` input.

Comment: could you please check, have you added used App\User; dependency ?

Comment: i have phonetoken column in db as well as user giving input value for phonetoken and yes i have App\User

Comment: try with User::all(), did you get all records from your table? if it will not then you have issue with model. so you can check like manually defining table name like this 'protected $table = 'your_table_name';'

Comment: try $request->phonetoken in place of $request->input('phonetoken')

Comment: did yuo add the class ? use App\User; ??

Comment: yes i used App\User

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because your eloquent cannot find the result.
Use dd($phonetoken) just to be sure the variable is being passed properly.
Also check phonetoken is in your user model.
Othet than this your code seems to be correct.

Comment: i found my answer it because i m manually entered a value in phonetoken field in DB but i don't know why it throwing error